# Why does postMessage called upon terminated worker not throw some error?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

After a web worker is terminated, why does `postMessage` not throw an error if I call it?

Is it possible to restart a worker, with an existing terminated instance, without the constructor `new Worker("same-worker.js")`?

```
const myWorker = new Worker("my-worker.js");
myWorker.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    const message = event.data;
    console.log("from worker", message);
    myWorker.terminate();
    myWorker.postMessage("");
    // what happens here, is only silence
    // Why not throw error?
});
myWorker.postMessage(""); //start it, maybe receive a response
```

Edit: I am asking about the rationale for this particular design. XHR, WebSocket and WebRTC immediately throw when trying to do stuff on a terminated instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [tl;dr jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Darker/70q5x0qh/1/)

I cannot answer *why*, because I am not the one who wrote javascript standard. But there is no indication whatsoever whether the worker has terminated or not.

### Detecting termination

If you need to detect this state, you must create your own API. I propose this simple function based draft as a starting point:

```
//Override worker methods to detect termination
function makeWorkerSmart(workerURL) {
    // make normal worker
    var worker = new Worker(workerURL);
    // assume that it's running from the start
    worker.terminated = false;
    // allows the worker to terminate itself
    worker.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
      if(e.data == "SECRET_WORKER_TERMINATE_MESSAGE") {
          this.terminated = true;
          console.info("Worker killed itself.");
      }
    });
    // Throws error if terminated is true
    worker.postMessage = function() {
        if(this.terminated)
            throw new Error("Tried to use postMessage on worker that is terminated.");
        // normal post message
        return Worker.prototype.postMessage.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    // sets terminate to true
    // throws error if called multiple times
    worker.terminate = function() {
        if(this.terminated)
            throw new Error("Tried to terminate terminated worker.");
        this.terminated = true;
        // normal terminate
        return Worker.prototype.terminate.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    // creates NEW WORKER with the same URL as itself
    worker.restart = function() {
        return makeWorkerSmart(workerURL);
    }
    return worker;
}
```

To also detect termination from the side of the worker, you will need to run this code inside every worker:

```
  function makeInsideWorkerSmart(workerScope) {
      var oldClose = workerScope.close;
      workerScope.close = function() {
          postMessage("SECRET_WORKER_TERMINATE_MESSAGE");
          oldClose();
      }
  }
  makeInsideWorkerSmart(self);
```

This will send message to the main window when worker terminates itself with `close`.

You can use it like this:

```
var worker = makeWorkerSmart(url);
worker.terminate();
worker.postMessage("test"); // throws error!
```

### Restarting the worker

As of restarting the worker: it is not technically possible to start from some previous state without saving it somewhere yourself. I propose this solution that I have implemented above:

```
worker.terminate();
worker = worker.restart();
```

You can also clone the worker this way as it doesn't stop the original worker.

Comment: tychus for the win

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the [terminate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/terminate) method of the worker

> immediately terminates the Worker. This does not offer the worker an opportunity to finish its operations; it is simply stopped at once.

I think that since the instance it's still there even if it's in this dead state, doing a `postMessage` will not throw, but since your worker is not processing any operation, it will simply do nothing.

There is no way to my knowledge from resuming a worker, but you could potentially set a Boolean pausing your processing via a message too, if you want to be able to resume it at will.